# How to reuse Datatable Options

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to create a dynamic system for Datatables.

I have this code where I attribute to all elements with the class "my-datatable" the DataTable main options. Next I want to add options for a specific Datatable.

```
    $(".my-datatable").DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
           'csv',
           'excel',
           'pdf',
      ],
      "language": {
           "search": "",
           "searchPlaceholder": "Search for any client’s information…",
           "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
           "info": "",
           "infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
           "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
           "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
           "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
           "processing": "Processing...",
           "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
      },
});


$(".my-datatable#specific-datatable").DataTable({
      "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
      columnDefs: [
           { targets: [0,2,4,5,7], orderable: false },
      ],
      "columns": [
           { "width": "5%" },
           { "width": "20%" },
           { "width": "10%" },
           { "width": "5%" },
           { "width": "20%" },
           { "width": "10%" },
           { "width": "15%" },
           { "width": "20%" },
      ]
});
```

Comment: its unclear what exactly you need.. :(

Answer (score 1):

[$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) can be applied in this case. After declaring the option of the first table, extend specific table property by the option using `$.extend` as following

```
var originalTableOption = {
      responsive: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
           'csv',
           'excel',
           'pdf',
      ],
      "language": {
           "search": "",
           "searchPlaceholder": "Search for any client’s information…",
           "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
           "info": "",
           "infoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
           "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
           "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
           "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
           "processing": "Processing...",
           "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
      },
};
$(".my-datatable").DataTable(originalTableOption);

var specificTableOnlyOption = {
      "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
      columnDefs: [
           { targets: [0,2,4,5,7], orderable: false },
      ],
      "columns": [
           { "width": "5%" },
           { "width": "20%" },
           { "width": "10%" },
           { "width": "5%" },
           { "width": "20%" },
           { "width": "10%" },
           { "width": "15%" },
           { "width": "20%" },
      ]
};
var specificTableOption = $.extend(specificTableOnlyOption, originalTableOption);
$(".my-datatable#specific-datatable").DataTable(specificTableOption);
```